# Bootstrap Dropdown Button names change when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu

I'm using dropdown buttons (4 buttons) to filter my content in my project, and i want that the button names change to the selected, so the user will not forget where he/she is. See figure.

[image: When clicked to two button name changes]

How can this be possible?

Thx in advance, and here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/aktuna/pen/FqKjb).

Comment: I had this exact issue with bootstrap. It is not in the configurable options to achieve what you need, so you will need to use another select-styling plugin.

Comment: I know that this is not configurable in Bootstrap. But with some javascript this can be possible, i guess. That's why i asked the question.

Comment: That's true. If you're asking for code, then you need to show what you have previously tried, as per the FAQ.

Comment: Why don't you use a `<select>`?

Comment: [Just an idea](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqbDm)

Comment: @Ravi why don't you post as an answer? BTW Your current solution looses the space before the caret.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i'm fairly new to javascript. But you're right.

Comment: @Ravi thx for the idea. Strange thing, in Firefox the button disappear after the click (tried  at chrome and firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to update the dropdown button text..

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/MjyR2AaLqn

Comment: Still relevant using Boostrap5 in 2022