# BS4 changing dropdown button value to match selected dropdown value?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get my BS4 dropdown menu to show the users selected value within the dropdown toggle button i.e. `.dropdown-toggle`

This question has been asked previously [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725688/bootstrap-dropdown-button-names-change-when-clicked) but it's a little outdated as it uses the BS3 Framework. It also doesn't provide a method where a dropdown is used multiple times.

My [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/x71kyoc9/12/) here, shows the issues I'm currently facing with how I've adapted the solution linked earlier.

**BS4 Dropdown**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle px-0 mr-3" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Sort by:
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Most Recent</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Popular</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Trending</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Acending</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Decending</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Jquery Attempt**

```
// Find all drop downs and check their classes.
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {

  // Find the dropdown toggle and append the text.
  $(".dropdown-toggle:first-child").append($(this).text());

});
```

> **The question:**
>
> How can I achieve my desired result without all dropdowns on the page
>   being affected? Additionally, I also need to remove the appended text
>   when a new value is selected.
>
> The result I am after; `button value = 'Sort by: Most Recent'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing I finally reached my goal using the following. Thanks @Vinee for providing the direction.

> You can check out a working example via; JSFiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/x71kyoc9/69/)**;

I've commented my code in the hopes it makes things a little easier to understand for anyone that picks this up.

---

### Here's what works for me...

```
$("document").ready(function() {

  // The timeout is to wait the click, so the elements can render correctly.
  setTimeout(function() {

    // Trigger the active class on DOM Ready...
    $('.btn-group').find('.active').trigger('click');

  }, 10);

});


// On dropdown child click do...
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {

  // Remove any existing 'active' classes...
  $(this).closest('.btn-group').find(".dropdown-menu a").removeClass('active');

  // Add 'active' class to clicked element...
  $(this).addClass('active');

  // Remove any previous '<span class="appended">'
  // This is needed so the values reset when a new option is clicked...
  $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.appended').remove();

  // Add a new '<span class="appended">' element -
  // and fill it with the clicked elements text
  $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('button').append('<span class="appended">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');

});
```

Hope this helps someone out there. It was nuisance for me... xD

Regards, -B.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
   //this one is add and remove active class
   $(this).closest('.btn-group').find(".dropdown-menu a").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
    //this one is for append text in button tag
    $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('button').append($(this).text())
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I got there in the end with a few tweaks. +1

Comment: it means alot to me :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<title>Lorem Ipsum Dolor </title>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.